# How to access socket for multiple reception using thread

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, network-programming, communication, serversocket

Hello I am new in networking field and using socket in Python
I am trying to access the function frame_reception_function() but I am getting error **"OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use"**
In  forward_send_received(), I am calling four different functions using thread, because in my work, this node can be received request frame form previous node and also need to forward this frame to next node and it is also receiving data frame form next node and send to the previous node. so it received two from two sides. How it is possible to access the same socket. I am also closing the connection but it does not work.
Can anybody help me to remove the above error (Address already in Used)

```
def frame_reception_function ():      
    print ("starting of frame reception")
    PORT = 12345
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    s.bind(('',PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn,address=s.accept()
    message=conn.recv(1024).decode()
    conn.close()
    recv_message=message.split(';')

    message_type=recv_message[0]
    if (received_message=='req_status'):
        print ('Received Message is req_status')

        previous_ip=recv_message[1]     
        return message_type,previous_ip,recv_message
    else:
        print ("received message is :",received_message)
        print ("Received from:",recv_message[4])
        ip=recv_message[4]
        #cmd = "arp -n " + str(ip) +  " | awk '/" + str(ip) + "/{print $3}'"          # Can we extract MAC address from IP instead of Broadcast address???
        #x = os.popen(cmd).read().strip()
        return recv_message[0],ip,recv_message


def forward_send_received():
    Frame_type,ip_address,received_message=frame_reception_function ()
    print ("after while")
    print (Frame_type)
    print (Frame_SrcAddr)
    print (ip_address)
    print (received_message)


    if (Frame_type=="req_status"):
        if (not Req_Frame_Relayed):             # Check Req_Frame_status

            forward_req_status_frame()
            Req_Frame_Relayed=True
            Probabilistic_Reliable_Broadcast(Frame_type)
            Send_Data_status_frame()
            Probabilistic_Reliable_Broadcast("current_node_data")
    else:

        if (Frame_SrcAddr not in Resp_forwarded_set):
            Resp_forwarded_set()
            forward_Data_status_frame(received_message)
            Resp_number=Resp_number+1
            Probabilistic_Reliable_Broadcast(Frame_type)

while (time.time()-start_time<Status_collecting_time_interval) and (Resp_number<Nmax):
    print ("starting of while ")
    Thread(target=forward_send_received).start()
```

Comment: @
Nick Craig-Wood 
 Please help.

Comment: You never *close* the socket after you're done with it. That means the binding you made in the first call will still be active in the second call.

Comment: @Some programmer dude i am closing the socket using following command   
 conn.close()
Can you help me if this is wrong then how i can close the socket ???

Comment: But where do you do `s.close()`? *That's* the socket you get an error about. Check the full error message you get, it will tell you what line you get the error on. I'll bet it's on the line `s.bind(('',PORT))`.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude  yes i am getting error at  s.bind(('',PORT)) line 
but after receiving message i am closing the socket then why it is closing 
even i am also include the s.shutdown(s.SHUT_RDWR) but command is not working. When I add this command then it is giving error "socket object has no attribute 'SHUT_RDWR'"
Where should I need to close the socket????
My error is at     s.bind(('',PORT)).

Comment: Just `close` it like you do with `conn`.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude where i am closing the connection" conn.close()" at this position, the programme is giving an error "Address already in use"
So at which posotion i should close the connection.......Where should i put this command "conn.close()"
tell the location in the program which i have send in First post

Comment: I'm telling you to use `s.close()` once you don't need `s` anymore.

Comment: @mkaran  can you tell me how i can use same socket when we are calling two or more function with small time of difference (ns). 
I am trying to access the same socket for transmission but immediateley it is not working but when i am giving some delay time of 5s or more then i it is working 
and Same problem is for receiving 
How i can use same socket  for receiving data from different client  at a same time?
I am using ' thread'   but it is not working. At that time its give error "Connection refuse"
Can you help me how i can use socket at both side transmission and reception side?